# LibreOffice error: "Either another instance of LibreOffice is accessing your personal settings or your personal settings are locked"

Tags: macos, libreoffice

When I try to open LibreOffice, I get the following error:

> Either another instance of LibreOffice is accessing your personal settings or your personal settings are locked.
>
> Simultaneous access can lead to inconsistencies in your personal settings. Before continuing, you should make sure user 'macowner' closes LibreOffice on host 'new-host.home'.
>
> Do you really want to continue?

I don't know why this started.  Also, there is only one account on this computer, I changed its name from "macowner" to its current name over a month ago.  Edit: I found out my computer kept the same file directory structure when I changed the username of my account, so my account's directory is called /Users/macowner.  This may be where LibreOffice gets the string for its error message.

I'm running LibreOffice 4.1 and OS X 10.7.5.

How do I remove this error?

Answer (score 8):

According [to the LibreOffice docs](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile) and [this similar Ask Ubuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127551/either-another-instance-of-libreoffice-is-accessing-your-personal-settings-or-yo), it stores a `.lock` file `~/Library/Application Support/libreoffice/4/user` on OS X to indicate a session is active and running.

To clean it up:

1. Make sure no instances of LibreOffice are currently running.
2. Open the Terminal application
3. Optional: Check to see if lock file exists, at the prompt type: `ls -l ~/Library/Application\ Support/LibreOffice/?/user/.lock`
   If you see "cannot access" this means the lock file is not present.
4. At the prompt type: `rm -f ~/Library/Application\ Support/LibreOffice/?/user/.lock`
5. Close the Terminal application
6. Start LibreOffice

Comment: I tried this (the command is actually: `rm -f "~/Library/Application Support/LibreOffice/4/user/.lock"`)
but it did not work.

Comment: To be more specific, the file was removed but the error continues to appear

Comment: See my amended answer. Try deleting non-version 4 .lock files as well.

Comment: I only had version 4 on my laptop.  However, I simply ignored the message and opened LibreOffice anyway.  For the record, this was triggered when I added charts to a LibreOffice Text Document (Word Equivalent).

Comment: I edited the command to work. There were problems with the quoting and `?  *` usage.

Comment: The direction "make sure ..." is not adequate since even advanced users cannot be "sure" of the process structure, directory structure, naming convention, etc. adopted by an application.   This is particularly the case if there are no instances running as no matter what combination of characters one greps in the ps output, it will come up with nothing obviously related to LibreOffice.

Comment: @JamesBowery for the purposes of this question, best effort works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

There are several lock files which may require deletion:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/LibreOffice/*/user/.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/LibreOffice/*/.lock
```

P.S.: This fix applies to OS X 10.9 and LibreOffice 4.2; Actual results may vary.